# Jmeter with www-Authenticate Basicrealm="Secured Area"

Tags: jmeter, www-authenticate

I am using Jmeter for performance testing and as i try to replay the request I am getting the following response header

I am using HTTP Authorization Manager with the following info
base url - example.com
username - username
password - kind
domain - example.com:80
Realm - 
Mech - Basic_digest

Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: 401
Response message: Unauthorized

Response headers:
HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
***WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Secured Area"***
Server: BigIP
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0

anythoughts on what I should try different

Thanks

Comment: 3/13 - I did resolve this by adding a authorization header and removing the authorization manager all together.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption 1: you're providing realm `Mech` and server expects it to be `Secured Area`.

As per [RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-11)

> The realm attribute (case-insensitive) is required for all
> authentication schemes which issue a challenge. The realm value
> (case-sensitive), in combination with the canonical root URL of the
> server being accessed, defines the protection space. These realms
> allow the protected resources on a server to be partitioned into a
> set of protection spaces, each with its own authentication scheme
> and/or authorization database. The realm value is a string, generally
> assigned by the origin server, which may have additional semantics
> specific to the authentication scheme.

So try changing "Realm" in to "Secured Area" in HTTP Authorization Manager to see how it goes.

Assumption 2: authentication is not "Basic". See [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) guide for details on how to bypass NTLM and Kerberos authentication challenges.

Answer (score 0):

3/13 - I did resolve this by adding a authorization header and removing the authorization manager all together.